# Finish Tab Activities

Tags: android, tabs, facebook-android-sdk

Here I am developing an app in which first user has to login via facebook. for that there is one Login activity with Login button. After successful login, user moves to tab activity say A. There are two more activities in Tab widget say activities B and C. Now, what I have to do is when user presses back button from activity C, user should move to activity B and when user presses back button from activity B, user should move to activity A. Now, when user presses back button from activity A, user should move to home screen or exit from the app. Now again, when user presses app icon to start the app, user should move to tab activity A directly, and not on the Login activity which has login button. I have created menu button for logout. when user logouts, should move to Login activity again...
What needs to be done?

Answer (score 1):

First of all save some setting in `SharedPreference` if user logged in and check the setting if user logged in then just by-pass to `Activity` A with

`intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)`.

If user logged out then just remove logged-in setting from `SharedPreference` . For back button press you should override back button press by overriding `onBackPressed()` function. In `Activity` C in `onBackPressed()` you should call

`sharedPrefrence.putString("selected_tab", 1);`

start you tab activity and in your tab activity `your_tab_host.setCurrentTab(sharedPreferences.getString("selected_tab")`

and when In `Activity` B in `onBackPressed()` you should call

`sharedPrefrence.putString("selected_tab", 0);`

start you tab activity and in your tab activity

`your_tab_host.setCurrentTab(sharedPreferences.getString("selected_tab")`

and finally when In `Activity` A in `onBackPressed()` then you should call `finish()`

Comment: @Harish..ur help is appreciated. But can u tell me how can I call tabhost object in my C activity, which is in my Tab activity class...

Answer (score 0):

In my tab activity(TabViewLayout), I created method,

```
public void switchTabBar(int tab) {
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(tab); 
    }

@Override
      public void onBackPressed() {
        // Called by children
        TabViewLayout.this.finish();
        }
```

In my Activity A,

```
@Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
          this.getParent().onBackPressed();   
        }
```

In my Activity B,

```
@Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
           TabViewLayout parentTab = (TabViewLayout) this.getParent();
         parentTab.switchTabBar(0); 
        }
```

In my Activity C (Final Activity),

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
         TabViewLayout parentTab = (TabViewLayout) this.getParent();
         parentTab.switchTabBar(1);

    }
```